# referring functions of 1st cs page in 2nd cs page

Tags: c#, selenium

Can we define a function in one cs page and refer that function in another cs page so that the functions designed in the 2nd cs page is executed with the 1st cs page function?

such like..in 1st cs page

```
Iwebdriver driver;
driver=new firefoxdriver();
```

In the 2nd cs page, I have many functions included based on the above function, so how can I refer this as a function in 2nd cs page so that code simplicity will exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very badly worded question but I can only assume that essentially what you are trying to achieve is to have the ability to call functions from one test in another test, or rather one *class* from another *class*.

This is basic C#.

Your code should be split out in a way that means this is easily achievable. So it means that your *tests* are totally seperate from your actual logic.

Using Page Objects is one way to go:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

This would mean you have a page like:

```
public class LoginPage
{
    public HomePage Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // do the login stuff
        // return the home page
    }
}

public class HomePage
{
    // some logic related to what the user can see on the home page.
}
```

You'd call it in a test like:

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
HomePage homePage = loginPage.Login(username, password);
```

Since it's now seperated, you could call `LoginPage.Login()` from *anywhere*.

The key here, is to **not** bundle all your logic into the tests themselves. As in, don't copy/paste the login code to login to your website into *each* test. Store it, like the above. The tests should be the steps you take, the page objects should define **how** those steps are taken. This way you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi Arran, thanx 4 ur reply.My new code,as you said above is given below.Please see how it can be restructured.

public class Class1
    {
        public Class1 drive()
        {
                IWebDriver driver;
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
Here i am facing an issue "not all code paths return a value".

And in the 2nd page I have functions like this..

driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("");

While defining each time locally I am getting new browser windows.So, for 10 funtions I am getting 10 windows.I have to reduce that to 1.please help...